# how to store negative floating-point numbers in C

Tags: c

As far as I know, double type in C is used to store floating-point numbers (e.g. 13,54201) and int type is for integers that can be negative (e.g. -44), now I'm writing a program and I need to store negative and floating-point values (e.g. -44,54201).

which data type should I use ?

Comment: Are you storing a floating-point value or an integer value? Do you *know* what "signed" means? Perhaps you should get [a good beginners book or two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to read?

Comment: "A signed integer is one with either a plus or minus sign 
in front. That is it can be either positive or negative.
An unsigned integer is assumed to be positive." You should google some stuff before posting questions.

Comment: The `double` type can store -44.54201 to a good level of precision. Note that C source code uses the `.` character to separate the integer part from the fraction part of a number in a _floating point_ constant, irrespective of the separator used in your locale.

Comment: sorry for my bad english I just edited the question

Comment: The `double` type can be used to store negative numbers. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have your terminology mixed up.  What you're calling "signed" numbers are actually called *fractional* numbers.

So what you're really asking for is a datatype that hold values that are both fractional and negative.  The `double` type can do just that.